# Confused: regular expression in shell and find

Tags: regex, shell, unix

[image]

I matched the data in directories r09 r10 by the following command:

```
find r[0-9]* -name '\*-ch24-\*' | sed -e 's|r[0-9]*/n_ch24/||' > sim_sets1.txt
```

but got confused, why it's not `find r[0-9]\* -name '.\*-ch24-.\*`?

Answer (score 2):

`*-ch24-*` is a glob.   `-name` matches globs.  For a glob, `*` matches zero or more of any character.

`.*-ch24-.*` is a regular expression.  If you want to match on regular expressions, use `-regex` instead of `-name`.  In a regex, `.` matches any character and `*` is a quantifier which means zero or more of the preceding character.

Comment: Indeed; also worth pointing out that escaping `*` as `\*` _inside a single- or double-quoted string_ will cause it to be treated as a literal by `find`, so it's implausible that `find r[0-9]\* -name '\*-ch24-\*'` worked as intended.

Comment: Oh \* is just for the editing markup here in stack-overflow, a typo. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @John1024 another quick question will be non-relevant to shell, but how to use command-line perl to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: @user1961679 Just to confirm, the backslashes that now appear in the question are editing markup, not part of an actual command?  Separately, to use command-line perl, replace the sed command with the very similar perl command: `perl -pe 's|r[0-9]*/n_ch24/||'`

Comment: @John1024 Bow// How about the 'find' part, is there any perl equivalent to that? Also perl -p: from man, '-p assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed', what does this mean, means 'print'? Thanks.

Comment: @user1961679 'print' means send the line to standard output.  Perl has a `file::Find` module to emulate the find command but I am not the right person to give you details on how it to use it.